# Linear transformation and integration

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

From what I have read, linear transformations can only reduce the dimension of a space.

I don't understand how can the integration operator be considered a linear transformation if it raises the exponent of a variable?

Also, how can multiplying by a another function (for ex: 2t+3) be considered a linear transformation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integration acts on the space of continuous functions. Let $f,g\in C^0(\mathbb{R})$, the space of continuous functions from the reals to the reals, and $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

$$\int (f+g)=\int (f)+\int(g) \\ \int(c\cdot f)=c\cdot\int (f).$$

This tells us that integration is a linear transformation. Since $\mathbb{R}[x]$, the space of polynomials, is contained (in some sense) in $C^0(\mathbb{R})$, we aren't increasing dimension by raising an exponent.

Multiplying by a scalar $\lambda$ is the same as multiplying by $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda\end{bmatrix}$, which is clearly a linear map.

Since the space $C^0(\mathbb{R})$ is something called an algebra, with product $(f,g)\mapsto f\cdot g$, multiplying two continuous functions will be bilinear.